# Possible flaw in Predestination (2014)

Tags: plot-explanation, predestination

This is in regards to the movie [Predestination](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2397535/).

This is an amazing movie, beautiful extrapolation of the short story and brilliant execution. I wonder if there is a tiny little flaw:

Jane would have had her first sexual experience with a man with funny scars all over his body. Later on when Jane becomes John and gets those exact funny scars, wouldn't that trigger a question in John's head - "Wait, I've seen the same scars on that guy who once had sex with when I was Jane". However in the movie, John is very surprised to know that the one who ruined Jane's life was John himself.

Could this have possibly been overlooked by the makers?

Comment: Maybe they kept the lights off?

Comment: Haha, Jane would perhaps then remember herself going - "eww, what's that snake like thing on your chest!!!".

Comment: Love makes people blind.

Comment: Additionally, at some point after the surgery, wouldn't John look in the mirror and think, Gee, I look just like my former lover?  I think John might have said something like he refused to look at himself, but still...

Comment: Jane or John didn't know about time travel until his future John showed him the device

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, it's easier for the character (Jane) to overlook the scars (especially if John chose to hide them) than it is for the filmmakers. What's more difficult to explain is the fact that, when she became John, Jane presumably didn't notice she now looked like her lost lover.

At first, I too thought it was intentionally ignored to keep the plot simple (I would still not rush into calling it a flaw). But would it have been *so* difficult to devise some way to make John even more discreet, to partially obscure his face?

The movie has two main points: identity and predestination. There are two moments in which John accepts the irony of fate (i.e., predestination) — the ultimate irony: that of becoming what he hated most. The last one was when he became his own archenemy, the Fizzle Bomber. And the first one?

You got it. She *accepted* to become he.

Comment: I was convinced of the flaw at reading first. But I researched and found that it did was taken care of. May not be the best way to tackle that but it definitely wasn't ignored. Following quote in John's story "I was always afraid to look in the mirror and see the person looking back at me. I held off as long as I could. Now, it didn't matter anymore.The person I knew was truly gone. Strange. Every time I looked at my new  appearance I was reminded of that bastard that ruined my life. That's some messed up irony I guess."

Comment: This quote appears to contradict my answer while it actually supports my point.