# How long were John and Jane together for in Predestination?

Tags: predestination

In Predestination, John goes back in time and falls in love with Jane. John later goes forward in time. But, during their time together, John and Jane conceive a child. This could be any length of time, from a single day to several years.

Does anyone know how long they were together for?

Comment: I can't fully remember but didn't she say that (after that one night) he disappeared and she never saw him again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvPd2.jpg) scheme, they were together from April  to June 1963 (to be precise from 4/3/1963 to 6/24/1963).

See also [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42918/16465) answer (by @Coomie) to another question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Reff: [Predestination Timeline](https://www.thisisbarry.com/film/predestination-2014-movie-plot-ending-explained/)

There is no exact details on how long Barkeeper leaves John with Jane. The timeline above seems to show some small duration, but no details. It may not have been too long, as in, perhaps a couple of months. This is because Jane was 18 and quite naive. It was the case of adolescent love may not have taken too long to happen.